# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in laravel

Tags: laravel

If I add this to api.php route I get this error

```
 trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in laravel     
 Route::get(['chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz' , 'API\QuizController@index']);
 Route::post(['chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz' , 'API\QuizController@store']);
 Route::put(['chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz/{id}' , 'API\QuizController@update']);
```

Error occurs in the line

```
protected function prefix($uri)
{
    return trim(trim($this->getLastGroupPrefix(), '/').'/'.trim($uri, '/'), '/') ?: '/';
}
```

Comment: what is `$this->getLastGroupPrefix()` and `$uri` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `[]` from your route.

```
 Route::get('chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz' , 'API\QuizController@index');
 Route::post('chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz' , 'API\QuizController@store');
 Route::put('chapter/{chapter_id}/quiz/{id}' , 'API\QuizController@update');
```